# Action Mailer Confirmation Emails - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I have successfully installed the [Clearance Gem](http://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) from ThoughtBot. Clearance sends a confirmation email upon a new sign_up and suggests adding:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

to your /environments/test.rb and development.rb. I have tried this and also

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '127.0.0.1', :port => 3000 }
```

But can't seem to get rails to send the email. As I am new to both Ruby and Rails, I am wondering if there is some step/config that ThoughtBot is assuming I have already done to send emails.

What am I doing wrong/missing?

UPDATE:
Just added notifier.rb

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
 def signup_notification(recipient)
  recipients recipient.email_address_with_name
       bcc        ["example@gmail.com"]
       from       "example@example.com"
       subject    "New account information"
       body       :account => recipient
     end

end
```

Comment: Did you forget to paste some lines from the Notifier? There is no function declaration.

Comment: I just use the code from: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Comment: you forgot the `def signup_notification(recipient)` line

Comment: Ah, just added that but still no go.

Comment: perhaps I need a "to" line? to "user.email"?

Comment: Ah, had to generate the mailer UserMailer. Missed that whoops.

Comment: Also had to add the google mail setting to development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to generate the user mailer model.

```
script/generate mailer UserMailer
```